# Getting CoreData Object values

Tags: ios, core-data

When I fetch my coreData, I get an object with this format :

```
<User: 0x7ff8e94de6f0> (entity: User; id: 0x7ff8e949eb10 <x-coredata:///User/tBDE724B5-CC13-4BB3-A4F9-A6DA57899C5A3> ; data: {
    birthday = "1995-11-11 23:00:00 +0000";
    email = someone@something.xx;
    name = "xxxx";
    password = nil;
    userUUID = "2fda609b-e49c-4d82-b205-58dc7a57b6bf";
})
```

When I try to put this object into a dictionary, My app crashes.

Which is the best way to parse this kind of data to get properties values (exemple email).

Regards

Comment: Please post some code where app crashes.

Comment: NSDictionary* dico = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)_userBeingSynced];

Comment: Your CoreData object has not to be an instance of NSDictionary. Core Data generates classes for your model and fetch requests returns objects of this classes.

Comment: Yes, that what I figured out, but the question how should I fetch properties in this core data Object.
Thanks

Comment: For example if Core Data created for you some class, let's name it "MyDataClass", you have to get properties like: MyDataClass * mdc = ...; NSString * someString = mdc.someStringProperty;

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev : If you mean that CoreData creates a User Object and I can access its properties via a simple user.email form example, the answer is no. Because im my user variable, I have only a string which is posted In my question <User :0x7 ....

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your code for better help.
You need to subclass your entity, like:

(I'm using Magical Record - https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord - but is not so different in CoreData, only for fetching all data but i think you've already done it)

```
NSArray *userFind = [User MR_findAll];
User *user = [userFind objectAtIndex:0]; //For example
NSLog(@"user birthday %@",user.birthday);
```

Hope this can help.